# Bulk import register device on azure iot hub using c# not working?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-iot-hub, bulk

I have taken bulk import code from [github msdn link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-bulk-identity-mgmt.md) 
but using this same code in console and in web application it is unable to register any new devices into iot hub.

it is creating a list of devices into blob file but why it is not able to successfully execute import job? i do not get any exception also.

```
class Program
    {
        static RegistryManager registryManager;

        static string connectionString = "iothub-connectionstring";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            BulkImport();

        }

        static string GetContainerSasUri(CloudBlobContainer container)
        {
            // Set the expiry time and permissions for the container.
            // In this case no start time is specified, so the
            // shared access signature becomes valid immediately.
            var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
            sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24);
            sasConstraints.Permissions =
              SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write |
              SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read |
              SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Delete;

            // Generate the shared access signature on the container,
            // setting the constraints directly on the signature.
            string sasContainerToken = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

            // Return the URI string for the container,
            // including the SAS token.
            return container.Uri + sasContainerToken;
        }

        private static async Task BulkImport()
        {
            try
            {
                registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

                StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("storeage-name", "storage-key");
                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, useHttps: true);
                // Create a blob client.
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("bulkiothubimport");
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("devices.txt");

                var containerSasUri = GetContainerSasUri(container);

                // Provision 1,000 more devices
                var serializedDevices = new List<string>();

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    // Create a new ExportImportDevice
                    // CryptoKeyGenerator is in the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common namespace
                    var deviceToAdd = new ExportImportDevice()
                    {
                        Id = i+"mydevicenew",
                        Status = DeviceStatus.Enabled,
                        Authentication = new AuthenticationMechanism()
                        {
                            SymmetricKey = new SymmetricKey()
                            {
                                PrimaryKey = CryptoKeyGenerator.GenerateKey(32),
                                SecondaryKey = CryptoKeyGenerator.GenerateKey(32)
                            }
                        },
                        ImportMode = ImportMode.Create
                    };

                    // Add device to the list
                    serializedDevices.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceToAdd));
                }

                // Write the list to the blob
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                serializedDevices.ForEach(serializedDevice => sb.AppendLine(serializedDevice));
                //await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();

                using (CloudBlobStream stream = await blob.OpenWriteAsync())
                {
                    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
                    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 500)
                    {
                        int length = Math.Min(bytes.Length - i, 500);
                        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, i, length);
                    }
                }

                // Call import using the blob to add new devices
                // Log information related to the job is written to the same container
                // This normally takes 1 minute per 100 devices
                JobProperties importJob =
                   await registryManager.ImportDevicesAsync(containerSasUri, containerSasUri);

                // Wait until job is finished
                while (true)
                {
                    importJob = await registryManager.GetJobAsync(importJob.JobId);
                    if (importJob.Status == JobStatus.Completed ||
                        importJob.Status == JobStatus.Failed ||
                        importJob.Status == JobStatus.Cancelled)
                    {
                        // Job has finished executing
                        break;
                    }

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }           

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the bulk import devices method are the REST API calls to the Azure IoT Hub service-facing endpoint. Using the *registryManager.ImportDevicesAsync* method is to create a background job in the Azure IoT Hub namespace. When the job has been accepted, the jobId is returned for its polling processing status.

Basically, we need two REST APIs such as the POST and GET job. More details can be found in the doc Service - [Create Import Export Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/createimportexportjob) and [Service - Get Import Export Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/getimportexportjob).

The following steps show how to test this bulk import devices job using the REST APIs:

1. Use the latest [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) for creating two containers such as one for *input* and the other one for *output* log messages. Also, this tool allows to generate a full uri address with a sas token for those containers.
2. Create a text file with the name *devices.txt* and following contains (example for provisioning two devices):

   ```
   {"id":"Device1",  "importMode":"Create", "status":"enabled", "properties":{"desired":{"abcd":12345 } } }
   {"id":"Device2",  "importMode":"Create", "status":"enabled", "properties":{"desired":{"abcd":12345 } } }
   ```
3. Upload the file *devices.txt* to the *input* container.
4. POST the job to the Azure IoT Hub

   ```
   POST https://{yourIoTHub}.azure-devices.net/jobs/create?api-version=2018-06-30
   Authorization:{yourIoTHubSasToken}
   body: 
   {
     "inputBlobContainerUri": "{inputContainerUriWithSasToken}",
     "outputBlobContainerUri": "{outputContainerUriWithSasToken}",
     "inputBlobName": "devices.txt",
     "type": "import"
   }
   ```

   the response should be:

   ```
   {
        "jobId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "startTimeUtc": "2019-01-06T16:19:54.9535051Z",
        "type": "import",
        "status": "enqueued",
        "progress": 0,
        "inputBlobContainerUri":  "xxxxxx",
        "outputBlobContainerUri": "xxxxxx",
        "excludeKeysInExport": false,
        "useSecondaryStorageAsSource": false
    }
   ```
5. Polling the job status until the job is either *completed* or *failed* or *cancelled*

   ```
   GET https://{yourIoTHub}.azure-devices.net/jobs/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2018-06-30
   Authorization:{yourIoTHubSasToken}
   ```

   the response:

   ```
   {
     "jobId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "startTimeUtc": "2019-01-06T16:19:54.9535051Z",
     "endTimeUtc": "2019-01-06T16:20:11.4043137Z",
     "type": "import",
     "status": "completed",
     "progress": 100,
     "outputBlobContainerUri": "",
     "excludeKeysInExport": false,
     "useSecondaryStorageAsSource": false
   }
   ```

Note, that the above steps 4. and 5. can be implemented using an Azure Functions to hide all details related to the storage and iot hub.

Comment: thanks for the more information, but why getting Failed to read devices blob from input container suddenly

Comment: Try to use two containers, one for input and the other one for output. Be sure the ouput container has a permission for rwdl. Also, when you run in the web application, try to yield your async BulkImport method processing using for example ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are seeing this behavior because your `BulkImport` is not awaited, meaning, in the first time the code hits an `await` inside the method, the code returns to the `Main` method and terminates the application.

Try changing the return value of `Main` to  `Task` (see [Async main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main)) instead of `void` and then `await` the call to `BulkImport`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await BulkImport();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: in console app it works after adding this code ` Task t1 =  BulkImport(); t1.Wait();`

in web application i check `importJob.Status completed` and after that it goes out of the method but still in iot hub it does not created new devices :(

Comment: sometimes getting this error - Failed to read devices blob from input container

Comment: @Neo This is not an azure iot hub problem, you should look at the dotnet  async programming technique in the web application. Beside that, the bulk method is a long running background task which is better handle in the service or for couple hundreds devices in the azure function (<5minutes) with an eventing notification.

Comment: thanks for the more information, but why getting  Failed to read devices blob from input container suddenly.

Comment: @Neo Probably had solved this but, just in case, Did you set your secret values correctly? I mean blob storage account, key, connection string, etc? And did you have a valid container inside that storage account?